# Swift singleton pattern in a framework

Tags: ios, singleton, swift2

I have a workspace in Xcode with my framework and with a test-app, so two xcode projects in one workspace.
In the framework I am building a `singleton` class, like so:

```
public let sharedInstance = MKUserPreferences()

class func A() {}
class func B() {}
```

But when I am in the app project and trying to call `MKUserPreferences.sharedInstance.A()`, it won't autocomplete and the method is not available. How do I solve this?

**EDIT: please keep in mind that `MKUserPreferences` is in a dynamically linked framework and I want to use it in my app (other project).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` and `B` are defined as `class` methods. Therefore, they can be accessed from the class `MKUserPreferences.A()` but not from an instance.

If you want them to be instance methods, just remove `class` from their definition:

```
public class MKUserPreferences {
    public static let sharedInstance = MKUserPreferences()
    private init() {} // Prevents using the default '()' initializer
    public func A() {}
    public func B() {}
}
```

Also, you need to explicitly define the methods you want to be public. In [Apple's words](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID11):

> A public type defaults to having internal members, not public members. If you want a type member to be public, you must explicitly mark it as such. This requirement ensures that the public-facing API for a type is something you opt in to publishing, and avoids presenting the internal workings of a type as public API by mistake.

Comment: They can't be accessed like `MKUserPreferences.A()`, because they are in the framework project (they HAVE to be public).
So in the framework project I have this `MKUserPreferences`, which has to be public (dynamically linked framework), but I want a sharedInstance to access internal methods.

Comment: It might be helpful then if you upload a sample project that exposes the problem somewhere we could download it and check it.

Comment: I have put the framework [here](http://github.com/jbehrens94/MagisterKit) and the app [here](http://github.com/jbehrens94/Voldoende).

Comment: Thanks! You just need to add `public` to your singleton methods. I  have updated my answer.

Comment: But then I could also access them without the sharedInstance, right?

Comment: No, it is true that they would be accessible from any instance of this class... But, since you are overriding the `init` and making it `private`. That ensures `sharedInstance` to be the only instance available, since the compiler throws an error when any class attempts to create another instance of this class.

Comment: @jbehrens94 NP! You can read more about how to create singletons in swift in this [very interesting post](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) on the different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In swift ,you can build a OneLine singleton class like this:

```
static let sharedInstance = MKUserPreferences()
private override init() {
        super.init()
}
func otherFunc(){}
```

and you can use like this:

```
MKUserPreferences.sharedInstance.otherFunc()
```

hope this  will helped you .

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didn't help me. It errors out `value of type MKUserPreferences has no member otherFunc`.

Comment: For your knowledge: in the framework project I have MKUserPreferences and in the app project I want to use that. So I made sharedInstance public.